# Layer Styling by Geometry Generator in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, geometry-generator

I am trying to create custom styling by using Geometry Generator in QGIS 3.6 but I got an error expression.

[image]

```
segments_to_lines ( $geometry)
 ramp_color('Viridis', 
  scale_linear( 
        length( 
            transform( 
     geometry_n($geometry ,
     @geometry_part_num),
     'EPSG: 4326' , 'EPSG: 26910'
     )
     ) / (
     m(end_point(
     geometry_n($geometry ,
     @geometry_part_num)))

    -
    m(start_point(
     geometry_n($geometry ,
     @geometry_part_num)))
     ) * 3.6,
     0,50,
     0,1
     ))
```

Comment: whats the error message if you click on 'more info'?

Comment: I can already see an error in your first line. QGIS will interpret this as your expression would end here. Set your brackets differently. Btw. what is your final goal, how should it look like?

Comment: Not 100% sure, that's why as comment.

Comment: One thing is first part, make segments from one line. And that's is in first line. The rest is color rendering, so it should be in place to set up color rendering.